# Ruby Metaprogramming ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

Suppose I have two models that are similiar. One is called Primer3Template which holds a subset of the fields on Primer3Parameter.

I would like puts only the fields from Primer3Template which exist in Primer3Parameter, as well as upcase the field name and add some string interpolation. I have the code partially working, like this:

```
> t = Primer3Template.new
> @primer3_parameter = Primer3Parameter.where(:batch_detail_id => 7146)
> t.attributes.each  do | name, value |
>     puts "#{name.upcase}="
>   end
```

So far so good, this outputs:

```
ID=
TYPE=
USER_ID=
BATCH_DETAIL_ID=
GENERATED=
STATUS=
P3_FILE_TYPE=
....etc
```

Next I am trying to output the value of the field from the @primer3_parameter variable, which has the same name as the current name being processed by the loop. I have tried this:

```
> t.attributes.each  do | name, value |
>     puts "#{name.upcase}=#{@primer3_parameter.name}"
>   end
```

But this is outputting the name of the class, which is not what I want:

```
ID=Primer3Parameter
TYPE=Primer3Parameter
USER_ID=Primer3Parameter
BATCH_DETAIL_ID=Primer3Parameter
GENERATED=Primer3Parameter
```

I want it to skip some fields, and print the value of the field, something like this:

```
BATCH_DETAIL_ID=7146
GENERATED=true
STATUS=active
P3_FILE_TYPE=Type2
```

I also tried this:

```
>  t.attributes.each  do | name, value |
> x = "@primer3_parameters.first.#{name}"
> puts "#{name.upcase}=#{x}"
> end
```

Which gave me:

```
ID=@primer3_parameters.first.id
TYPE=@primer3_parameters.first.type
USER_ID=@primer3_parameters.first.user_id
BATCH_DETAIL_ID=@primer3_parameters.first.batch_detail_id
GENERATED=@primer3_parameters.first.generated
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use eval for this. You might get hurt!

Here is a good alternative

```
attribute_names = Primer3Template.accessible_attributes
@primer3_parameter = Primer3Parameter.where(:batch_detail_id => 7146)
attribute_names.each do |attr_name|
  puts "#{attr_name.upcase}=#{@primer3_parameter.read_attribute(attr_name)}"
end
```

Instead of `@primer3_parameter.read_attribute(attr_name)` I think you could do `@primer3_parameter[attr_name]` but I'm not sure if there are any drawbacks

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
@primer3_parameters = Primer3Parameter.where(:batch_detail_id => 7146)
```

returns a collection association. If you want to traverse the Primer3Parameter associated records you have to iterate through them. Like this:

```
@primer3_parameters.each do |primer3_parameter|
  primer3_parameter.attributes.each do |name, value|
  .....
```

and the rest is how you did it before.

Comment: Hi @ChuckE , thanks for your answer. I would like to traverse the t variable (Primer3Template) and use the name to retrieve the value of the same field on Primer3Parameter. I am thinking instance_variable_get will do it but I can't quite get the syntax right.

Comment: but your @primer3_parameter variable is not a Primer3Parameter instance, it is a collection of many.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!!

```
> t = Primer3Template.new
> p = Primer3Parameter.where(:batch_detail_id => 7146).first
> t.attributes.each do |name, value|
>     x = eval("p.#{name}")
>     puts "#{name.upcase}=#{x}"
>   end
```

Output

```
ID=15
TYPE=Primer3Parameter
USER_ID=
BATCH_DETAIL_ID=7146
GENERATED=false
STATUS=ready
P3_FILE_TYPE=settings
P3_FILE_ID=
P3_FILE_FLAG=false
P3_COMMENT=
SEQUENCE_EXCLUDED_REGION=
SEQUENCE_FORCE_LEFT_END=-1000000
SEQUENCE_FORCE_LEFT_START=-1000000
```

Did I mention I **love** Ruby? I hope this helps someone else.

**EDIT - Improved Solution**

- Doesn't requiring instantiating the template class
- Only returns the accessible fields which is exactly what I wanted

.

```
 Primer3Template.accessible_attributes.each do |name|
      x = eval("p.#{name}")
      puts "#{name.upcase}=#{x}"
 end
```

Comment: Maybe you can use `x = p.send(name)` to process a Dynmamic Dispatch instead of using `eval`

Comment: ` Primer3Template.accessible_attributes.each do |name|
      x = p.send(name)
      puts "#{name.upcase}=#{x}"
 end` [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: The trick was not really an answer to your question, just a way to avoid `eval` function. My goal is reached if improvement is useful ;)

Comment: Do you want all the accessible attribute names from `Primer3Template` printed out, even when there isn't a corresponding accessible attribute in `Primer3Parameter`?

Comment: @Peter Alfvin yes that's exactly what I want. Primer3Parameter is a superset of Primer3Template (both models are mapped to the same physical table via STI)

Comment: Then you're all set. Note that the `do end` block in @ardochhigh's answer can be shortened further to `{puts "#{name.upcase}=#{p.send(name)}"}`